# How to Count Occurence of Matrix in List of Matrices?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a list of matrices, for example a list of numpy arrays:

```
list = [np.array([[0,1],[1,1]]),
        np.array([[1,0],[0,0]]),
        np.array([[0,1],[1,1]])]
```

and I would like to count the occurence of each matrix. Thus, the desirable output is something like:

```
np.array([[0,1],[1,1]]): 2
np.array([[1,0],[0,0]]): 1
```

I could imagine that this might be possible using numpy or pandas. As I need to use the matrices for arithmetic operations, I'm looking for a solution which avoids flattening the matrices. I'm aware that np.unique is able to count the occurences of flat arrays in a list.

Comment: `np.unique` can also count non-flat matrices and deliver you expected results, but you'll want to make a single numpy matrix, not a python list of arrays. (also don't use `list` as a variable name)

Comment: I agree with @MarkMeyer try something like `np.unique(np.stack(list), axis=0, return_counts=True)` you'll get all the info you want, this works only if all arrays in your list are same shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
pd.Series(my_list).astype(str).value_counts()
```

---

```
[[0 1]\n [1 1]]    2
[[1 0]\n [0 0]]    1
dtype: int64
```

Or:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

for arr in my_list:
    d[str(arr)] += 1
    
d = dict(d)
print(d)


{'[[0 1]\n [1 1]]': 2, '[[1 0]\n [0 0]]': 1}
```